# Counters in Citrix Netscaler and their meanings (Diff) or (Actual)

Tags: citrix, reporting, performance-counters, netscaler

I try to configure some Citrix Netscaler Command Center Reports. When I configure a Custom Report I can choose between different available counters. Per example:

- Vserver Hits
- Vserver Hits(Actual)
- Vserver Hits(Diff)

Can someone explain me what is the difference between these counters? Especially what the (Diff) means.

In general there are multiple counters available with an (Actual) or (Diff) ending.

Comment: Can't find documentation on that. Try the [official NetScaler ADC subforum](http://discussions.citrix.com/forum/1356-netscaler-application-delivery/). (Since there seems to be no dedicated official "Command center" subforum.)

Comment: Good idea, i've opened a topic there: [link](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/373121-counters-in-citrix-netscaler-command-center-and-their-meanings-diff-or-actual/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical support of Citrix was able to answer my question:

- The OID used for these 3 counters is the same, but we have an internal logic in Command Center to derive & differentiate them
- “Vserver Hits” corresponds to “Rate(/s)” value of stat lb vs in NS
- “Vserver Hits(Actual) corresponds to “Total”  value of stat lb vs in NS
- “Vserver Hits(Diff)" corresponds to difference in polled value of Vserver Hits(Actual)  [current polled  Vserver Hits(Actual) – Previous polled Vserver Hits(Actual)]

To be absolutely sure about the "Vserver Hits(Diff)" counter, I've checked what happens when I do increase the polling interval. I changed the value from 300 seconds to 600 seconds. In my view the output of the report should also increase by the factor of two. And indeed, the result was as I thought :-)
[Screenshot of Vserver Hits (Diff) Report which shows the effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mub4Y.png)